# Div with content next to div with no content layout error

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The two following documents display very incorrectly in Chrome (unsure of other browsers) where the tops of the divs do not line up. I am wondering if there is a way to fix this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body,html
      {
        height:100%;
      }
      .test
      {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        width:30%;
        height:30%;
        outline:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="test">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body,html
      {
        height:100%;
      }
      .test
      {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        width:30%;
        height:30%;
        outline:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="test">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only fix I have currently found is

```
  .test:after
  {
    content:"\0";
  }
```

This dukes the browser into thinking `.test` has content, but perhaps there is another way to fix it?

---

EDIT: To clarify, the question I am seeking an answer for is not **"How do I align the divs at the top"**, it is more along the lines of **"why does content vs no-content vs nested-divs effect div placement on a page and is there a non-ugly fix?"**

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float: left;` or `float: right;` to the .test divs will make them line up at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Relative nested inside relative is causing this issue , you may try this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hswwsxbt/3/)

```
 <div class="test">
  <div class="test">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="test">&nbsp</div>
</div>
<div class="test">&nbsp</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to have divs nested in divs nested in divs of variable amount, therefore `position:absolute` cant be used.

Comment: if this doesnt solve your issue , please give an exact example of what you wll be doing.